# Bind Ctrl and Ctrl+key by using jquery.hotkeys.js

Tags: jquery, hotkeys

I'm using jquery (latest version) together with `jquery.hotkeys.js`.
What I would like to acchieve is:
I would like to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (ok that is an easy one) but in addition I have to capture the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> only because I'm using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for gathering selections.

At the moment I don't see how to solve it with `jquery.hotkeys.js`.
Has anyone any idea as to this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not familiar with that plugin, but for just catching a *keyup* / *keydown* event with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, you can just bind

```
$( document.body ).keyup(function( event ) {
   if( event.which === 17 ) {
       // yay
   } 
});
```

I'm not super sure if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> has the keyCode of 17 on every platform out there, that you might want to double check.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you are right but the handling using jquery.hotkeys.js is quite easy: 
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+a', fn);
$(document).unbind('keydown', 'Ctrl+a', fn);
So it would be quite comfortable to use the plugin.
But $(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl', fn);
seem doesn't work - unfortunately. But if someone has an idea?

Comment: @Walter: try binding to `document.body`